# Vite React cant access backend/appointment/create

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404, vite

I've been debugging this a whole day but still can't get rid of it. I'm trying to make an appointment on BookAppointment.jsx but it says:
**Console:**

```
http://localhost:5173/backend/appointment/create 404 (Not Found)
```

but when I'm in the Appointments.jsx (with AddAppointment.jsx component), I can create an appointment without a problem.

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const userRole = currentUser.role;
        let firstName = userRole === 'customer' ? currentUser.firstName : formData.firstName;
        let lastName = userRole === 'customer' ? currentUser.lastName : formData.lastName;
        let email = userRole === 'customer' ? currentUser.email : formData.email;

        const appointmentData = {
            schedule: formData.date,
            technicianName: formData.technician,
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            phone: formData.phoneNumber,
            email: email,
            services: formData.services,
            address: formData.address,
            landmark: formData.landmark,
            patient: animalInfo.map(animal => ({
                typeOfAnimal: animal.typeOfAnimal,
                numberOfHeads: animal.numberOfHeads,
                age: animal.age,
            })),
        };
        console.log('Submitted appointmentData:', appointmentData);


        try {
            const response = await fetch('/backend/appointment/create', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(appointmentData),
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log('Appointment created:', data);
                setAppointments((prevAppointments) => {
                    const updatedAppointments = prevAppointments ? [...prevAppointments, data] : [data];
                    return updatedAppointments;
                });
                // Add system log after creating the appointment
                const systemLogResponse = await fetch('/backend/logs/add', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        accountId: currentUser._id,
                        name: `${currentUser.firstName} ${currentUser.lastName}`, // Include lastName in the name field
                        role: currentUser.role,
                        dateTime: new Date(),
                        activity: `Created an appointment this coming ${appointmentData.schedule} for ${appointmentData.firstName} ${appointmentData.lastName}`,
                    }),
                });

                if (systemLogResponse.ok) {
                    console.log('System log added:', await systemLogResponse.json());
                } else {
                    console.error('Error adding system log:', systemLogResponse.statusText);
                }

                // You can reset the form or perform other actions after successful creation.
            } else {
                console.error('Error creating appointment:', response.statusText);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error creating appointment:', error);
        }
    };
```

**BookAppointment.jsx:**

```
 const handleStep3Submit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    // Perform any additional logic for Step 3 form submission here
    const appointmentData = {
      address: e.target.address.value,
      landmark: e.target.landmark.value,
      animalType: selectedAnimalType,
      age: e.target.age.value,
      numberOfHeads: e.target.numberOfHeads.value,
      selectedServices,
    };

    // Create the appointment
    const response = await fetch('/backend/appointment/create', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(appointmentData),
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      // Redirect to the dashboard after successful appointment creation
      navigate('/dashboard');
    } else {
      console.error('Error creating appointment:', response.statusText);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Step 3 Form Submission Error:', err);
  }
};
```

Also heres my vite config

```
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/backend': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

My frontend is running on **http://localhost:5173/**
While my backend is **http://localhost:3000**

I've already tried creating an appointment using Insomnia, so far, I can access the endpoint and can create an appointment.

Comment: Shouldn't this call `http://localhost:5173/backend/appointment/create` go to port `3000`, instead of `5173`?

Comment: Ok, I suppose `http://localhost:5173/backend` should redirect to `http://localhost:3000`, right? Can you try directly putting `http://localhost:3000/appointment/create` in your `fetch` call and see if it works?